# How to use JSON_ARRAY_APPEND when path does not exist in JSON doc?

Tags: mysql, json, sql-update, mysql-function

Imaging the existing JSON doc:

```json
{
  "first": "data",
  "second": [1,2,3]
}
```

When I try to execute:

```
JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(doc,'$.third',4)
```

I expect mysql to create the parameter as an empty array and add my element into that array resulting in:

```json
{
  "first": "data",
  "second": [1,2,3],
  "third": [4]
}
```

This however is not the case. I am trying to do this in an UPDATE query to add data into the db using something similar to:

```sql
UPDATE mytable 
   SET myjson=JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(myjson,'$.third',4) 
 WHERE ...
```

I am using mysql 8.0.16 if that makes any difference. I am not getting any errors, just `0 row(s) affected`

Comment: I was able to work around this by manually creating the `"third":[]` parameter on every item. I would like to know if this can be done without that step though for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `JSON` is not an array, so rather than `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND()`, you can consider using `JSON_MERGE_PATCH()` function if the order of the keys do not matter :

```
UPDATE mytable 
   SET myjson = JSON_MERGE_PATCH(myjson, '{"third": [4]}')
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=37a8cd711d9fb17fe02521e57e4757a9)</kbd>

*According to [Normalization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-normalization) principle ; To make lookups more efficient, MySQL also sorts the keys of a JSON object. You should be aware that the result of this ordering is subject to change and not guaranteed to be consistent across releases.*

Comment: I will look more into this function, but I assume by saying preserve that is preserves any data that was already in the array if it existed.

Comment: @amaster well, you're right. we'd better considering `JSON_MERGE_PATCH()` instead then.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I actually want to use the `JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE` method though for my case, I wasn't very clear on that, sorry. I did find an article going into depth about the difference: https://database.guide/json_merge_patch-vs-json_merge_preserve-in-mysql-whats-the-difference/